# Integer division round off to 2 decimal places in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I need to divide 2 integers and the result should be rounded off to 2 decimal places.
Actual numbers look like this:

```
Select 3/5
```

To achieve rounding off to 2 decimal places multiplied the numerator with a float:

```
select round(3.0 / 5 , 2)
```

Tried casting both the numbers as decimal numbers like this:

```
select round ( CAST (3 as decimal(3,2)) /  CAST (5 as decimal(3,2)) , 2)
```

But the result contains more than 2 decimal places.

The expected result is:

```
0.60
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: 3/5 = 0.6000 so how do you get to 0.66 ?

Comment: `select cast(100*3/5 as decimal(5,2))/100`...i've always thought that would be more efficient since it only does one cast...no idea if that notion is based in fact. never done any performance tests

Comment: While, as has been pointed out, you aren't going to get `0.66` out of that calculation no matter what, you've stumbled upon the answer yourself already: cast the *final result* to the desired precision, e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(3, 2), 3.0 / 5)`. (And note that `3.0` is *not* a `FLOAT` but a `DECIMAL(2, 1)`. `3e0` would be a `FLOAT`.)

Comment: If you want .66~ then that would be 2/3, 4/6, etc. Also `ROUND` doesn't change the scale of a `decimal`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types). If you `ROUND` the value `1.23456` to 2 decimal places you get `1.23000` because the value will still be a `decimal(6,5)`. If you specifically want to change the scale of a `decimal` then `CONVERT`/`CAST` it. `CONVERT(decimal(3,2),4.0 / 6)` = `0.67`, `ROUND(4.0 / 6,2)` = `0.670000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we divide we can use an integer, which will produce an integer result, or a decimal by adding a decimal point (with or without a zero) which will give a decimal result with the number of decimal places determined by the format, or a floating point by adding an e, which will use the number of significant decimal places without trailing zeros. The following test schema demonstrates the difference between them.

I would seem that `ROUND(2e/3,2)` is the most concise way to arrive at 2 decimal places.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   3e/5 FloatingPoint,
>   3./5 DecimalDivision,
>   CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), 3./5) DecimalDivision,
>   Round(3e/5,2) RoundedFloat
> ```

> ```
> FloatingPoint | DecimalDivision | DecimalDivision | RoundedFloat
> ------------: | --------------: | --------------: | -----------:
>           0.6 |        0.600000 |            0.60 |          0.6
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   2e/3 FloatingPoint,
>   2./3 DecimalDivision,
>   CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), 2./3) DecimalDivision,
>   Round(2e/3,2) RoundedFloat
> ```

> ```
>     FloatingPoint | DecimalDivision | DecimalDivision | RoundedFloat
> ----------------: | --------------: | --------------: | -----------:
> 0.666666666666667 |        0.666666 |            0.67 |         0.67
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3ed727462675cf9a8d277f455acaf25f)*

Comment: Adding a decimal point does *not* yield a floating-point number. This misconception is natural and persistent, but what you get that way is a `DECIMAL` literal, and hence also a division of two `DECIMAL` quantities. A floating-point literal can be formed through exponential notation (`2e`). Hence `2e / 3` is a true `FLOAT` (and does not require further conversion). Note also that `CAST` and `CONVERT` both work with any type; `CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, ...` AND `CAST(... AS FLOAT)` are the same thing, so there's no need to mix and match here.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thank you for the correction. I have modified my explanation.